# In Rails 5.1, how do I write a finder method for a has_many and then belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.1.  I have the following models ...

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :plans, :dependent => :nullify


class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :associate
```

I want to write a finder query that returns all Member objects with a Plan that has an "associate" with an ID of "1", "2", or "3".  How do I do that?  I tried writing a finder for only finding the ID, "1", but am getting this error upon evaluation ...

```
[8] pry(main)> Member.where(:plans => {:associate => {:id => "1"}}).count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Members" WHERE "associate"."id" IS NULL
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "associate"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "members" WHERE "associate"."id" ...
                                              ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "members" WHERE "associate"."id" IS NULL
from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:611:in `async_exec'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first use `joins` to create an `INNER JOIN` query. After that you're able to access the join tables:

```
Member.joins(plans: :associate).where(associates: { id: 1 })
```